# Pasted text at the top of page

Tags: html

I want to add pasted text (that text goes down when user goes down of the page, etc.) at the top of my page, when somebody haven't got enabled JavaScript, something like that :

[image]

How to do this ? Is there any way to that using JavaScript or HTML ? I want not to use jQuery, because I don't know that language so good.

@EDIT : Sorry, that was my error - that cannot use JavaScript if user doesn't have JS enabled :)

Comment: Using javascript to display a message about not having javascript seems problematic. I recommend CSS -- SO uses fixed positioning.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to Show One <div> if Javascript Enabled and a Different <div> if It's Not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963214/how-to-show-one-div-if-javascript-enabled-and-a-different-div-if-its-not)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create sticky header bar for a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212624/how-to-create-sticky-header-bar-for-a-website)

Comment: Have you considered using `<noscript>`? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: @Shaun I'm using that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample how you can make a info bar like SO:

HTML:

```
<noscript><div id="noscript"><p>NO JAVASCRIPT</p></div></noscript>
```

CSS:

```
div#noscript {

    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 10px 0; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    background: red;
    z-index: 99999;
}

div#noscript p { 

    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

Here the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLPtL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/AJUxayA/6/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="no_js_header">test</div>
  <div id="content">content</div>
  <div style="margin-top: 2200px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
#no_js_header {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}
```

---

(uncomment for activation in the jsbin)

```
document.getElementById('no_js_header').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the noscript tag...

```
<noscript>
    <div>
        <p>ahhh, javascript is disabled!</p>
    </div>
</noscript>
```