# Removing <div> if Javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

I have a list that is part of a larger menu:

```
<ul>
<li>Menu Item 1</li>
<li>Menu Item 2</li>
<li>Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide the list completely IF Javascript is disabled in the web browser.

I tried one solution that works, but it uses the **noscript** element within **head**, which is not compliant with XHTML.  I'm seeking a solution that complies with XHTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Show One <div> if Javascript Enabled and a Different <div> if It's Not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963214/how-to-show-one-div-if-javascript-enabled-and-a-different-div-if-its-not)

Comment: maybe use a javascript detect script and only if they have it enabled then load the menu with an ajax call with something like jquery.

Comment: Based on your requirements I've removed the `html` tag and added the `xhtml` tag.

Comment: Reverse the logic.  Add items if javascript is enabled via javascript.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson nice and valid trick :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would work

```
<div class="hidden">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1
    <li>Menu Item 2
    <li>Menu Item 3
  </ul>
</div>

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
$(function()
{
  $(".hidden").show();
});
```

Comment: Any thoughts on why this code works fine on a development but not a live server?

Answer (score 6):

You might be better going the other way and only displaying it if javascript is enabled.

Create a class something like the below...

`.JSenabled {display:none}`

Toggle class on `$(document).ready()` using `$('.JSenabled').show()`.

Add this class to any elements you want to hide when JS is unavailable.

You'll also need to link the jQuery library.

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It can be done without jQuery, though the syntax is much easier with it.

Comment: Introducing jQuery just to show one divider is very illogical and completely unnecessary.

Comment: *completely illogical* is too strong. It might be inefficient, but it does cover all bases. Also, it's not unlikely the OP is already using jQuery for other purposes.

Comment: It maybe a little illogical, but the powers of jquery and it's user friendlyness make it a good place to get started introducing such functions and triggers learning new functionality. Lots of people include it now anyway, and it barely affects page speed loading it, because most people have the google version cached anyway.

Comment: And the answer selected by the OP shows they do have jQuery installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the ul with css, and then use javascript to show it.

In this way, the ul will not show if the javascript is disabled, because it is hidden my the css.

### jQuery Way:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() }
   $('ul').show();
});
```

When using jQuery, remember to put the jQuery libery in the `<head>` section of your pages:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

[jQuery Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgvC2/)

---

### Plain Javascript Way:

If you don't want to use jQuery, but plain javascript you can add an ID to your `<ul>` and then show it with javascript like this:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Menu Item 1</li>
    <li>Menu Item 2</li>
    <li>Menu Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('menu').style.display = "block";
```

[Plain Javascript Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgvC2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "hidden" css id and then only show that object if javascript if enabled:

HTML:

```
<div class="hidden" id="hiddenDiv">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item 1
    <li>Menu Item 2
    <li>Menu Item 3
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#hiddenDiv{
  display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = "block";
};
```